# magnetism induced current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]

Hi, I have a question about magnetism. I learned 2 rules and they are confusing me.

1. the right handrule which says: stop the magnetic field lines with the palm of your right hand and point your thumb so it's pointing in the direction of velocity vector. The tip of your fingers point to the side with high polarity $(+)$ and your wrist to the side with low polarity $(-)$

so following this rule I would say in the example in the picture: 
$$Vp < Vq --> Q= + and P= - $$
so I(current) will from Q to P.

2. the other rule is (lenz's law: wrap your hand around the wire so that your fingers go in the opposite way compared to the magnetic field lines. Stick out your dumb and this is the way the current will flow.

in the example my dumb will point to Q. So I(current) flows from $P(+)$ to $Q(-)$. I flows from high potential to low potential so: $Vp> Vq$

so my question,

- which potential is bigger $Vp$ or $Vq$?

help would be appreciated because I just don't see it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here P has a higher potential than Q. The basic principle here is that the induced current should try to oppose the increasing magnetic flux that is going inside the loop. So the current in the loop will have a direction such that the magnetic field produced by it in the loop counteracts the increasing magnetic flux, i.e in the downward direction. So we have concluded that the direction of magnetic field produced should be downward. This can be only produced by a current flowing from P to Q and hence P has a higher potential than Q.